# Testing input for positive number in c++

Tags: c++

I am making a program that asks the user what items they want to buy and how much of each item, then calculates the total amount for all.  What i was wondering is how i would go about making sure that the input entered for "amount" is a positive number only.  I have searched on here and only found answers for the same type of question languages other than C++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
//Constants for menu
const int
    NOTEBOOK = 1,         //Represents choice for notebook
    PEN = 2,              //Represents choice for pen
    PENCIL = 3,           //Represents choice for pencil
    EXIT = 4;             //Exits the program

//Constants for Prices
const double
    NOTEPRICE = 1.50,     //Represents notebook price
    PENPRICE = .30,       //Represents pen price
    SPECPEN = .25,        //Represents pen price when coupon code is entered
    PENCILONE = .20,      //Represents pencil price when 1-4 are purchased
    PENCILFIVE = .15,     //Represents pencil price when 5-9 are purchased
    PENCILTEN = .10;      //Represents pencil price what 10 or more are purchased

int
    choice,               //Represents what number choice the user selects
    amount;               //Represents the amount of the item selected that the user wants to purchase

double
    totalPrice,
    noteTotal = 0,
    penTotal = 0,
    pencilTotal = 0;

string
    coupon;




do
{
    //Display Menu
    cout << "\tWelcome to Martin Office Supplies\n\n";
    cout << "Our inventory\n\n";
    cout << "1. Notebooks\n";
    cout << "2. Pens\n";
    cout << "3. Pencils\n";
    cout << "4. Exit\n\n";
    cout << "Please make a selection: ";
    cin >> choice;


    //Validates menu selection
    while (choice < NOTEBOOK || choice > EXIT)
    {
        cout << "Sorry we dont sell that item.\n";
        cout << "Please make another selection.\n";
        cin >> choice;
    }


    //Responds to users menu selection
    switch (choice)
    {
    case NOTEBOOK:
        cout << "How many notebooks would you like to buy?";
        cin >> amount;
        noteTotal = amount * NOTEPRICE;
        cout << "The subtotal for the notebook(s): " << noteTotal << endl << endl;
        break;

    case PEN:
        cout << "How many pens would you like to buy? ";
        cin >> amount;
        cout << "Please type in a coupon code or NONE ";
        cin >> coupon;

        if (coupon == "pen123")
        {
            penTotal = SPECPEN * amount;
        }
        else
        {
            penTotal = PENPRICE * amount;
        }

        cout << "The subtotal for the pen(s): " << penTotal << endl << endl;
        break;

    case PENCIL:
        cout << "How many pencils would you like to buy? ";
        cin >> amount;
        if (amount <= 4)
        {
            pencilTotal = PENCILONE * amount;
        }
        else if (amount >= 5)
        {
            pencilTotal = PENCILFIVE * amount;
        }
        else if (amount >= 10)
        {
            pencilTotal = PENCILTEN * amount;
        }
        cout << "The subtotal for the pencil(s): " << pencilTotal << endl << endl;
    }
    totalPrice = noteTotal + penTotal + pencilTotal;
    cout << "Thank you for your order\n\n\n";
    cout << "Your total is $ " << totalPrice << endl;

} while (choice != EXIT);
return 0;

}
```

Comment: 1. Read some string 2. Check if the string represents for positive integer

Comment: Please limit your listing to the portion of your code relevant to the question.

Comment: you could use unsigned types too...

Comment: @AustinFrench Unsigned types itself will accept 0, which is not positive.

Comment: @MikeCAT True, but many times when we say "positive" we mean non-negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try :

```
int amount=0;
cout << "How many notebooks would you like to buy?";
cin >> amount;
while (amount<=0){
    cout << "you need to enter a positive number";
    cout << "How many notebooks would you like to buy?";
    cin >> amount;
}
```

Comment: @MikeCAT: Mathematically speaking 0 is not positive or negative, but traditionally in computers (which use a sign bit, e.g. for IEEE754 floating point types or even two's complement), numbers are generally considered positive when the sign bit is not set.

Answer (score 0):

Three options come to mind. You can also combine these to achieve better user experience:

- Provide the information to the user that he/she is supposed to enter only positive values - this is probably the most unreliable of all since typos are always an option when entering something hence this is more of a *nice to have* feature
- Limit what the user can input - whenever you don't want your user to do something you always have the option to simply limit his/her actions when interacting with your application. You can parse the input and if the value is less than your threshold (in this case - a negative and maybe also zero) just return to the previous state notifying the user that he/she did something wrong and also (very important!) provide active feedback - tell him/her how to fix the problem
- Using `unsigned` - store whatever number you have without a sign. Both negative and positive numbers will be treated equally until you actually perform some calculation when an `unsigned` may become a positive number. The problem with this way of doing things is that you will have no way of providing feedback to the user what has happened. Since `-1` will be treated the same way as `+1` you will create a sort of obfuscation about the internal state of your application. This is bad practice because the user has to be in control and also know what is happening.

In my opinion the second option would be the best way of handling the situation because it not only prevents the application of continuing its work with an input you know is incorrect but you also give your user information how to fix the situation.